# Error in Kendo Grid Export to excel "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in jQuery.js file

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to export kendo grid to excel, Then I am having error in console. Please help me if anyone knows about it.Thanks in Advance.

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.map (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:461:18)
    at init.toDataURL (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js:30:19702)
    at init.<anonymous> (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js:30:27764)
    at Object.proxy (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:513:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3230:33)
    at fire (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3073:30)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3185:7)
    at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) [as resolve] (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3275:34)
    at init.<anonymous> (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js:30:22489)
    at Object.proxy (http://lm.stage.cargoclix.net/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:513:14)
```

and this is my Bower.json file code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "json-formatter": "0.6.0",
    "angular-route": "1.5.8",
    "angular-local-storage": "0.5.2",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.2.0",
    "toastr": "2.1.3",
    "moment": "2.15.1",
    "angular-translate": "2.11.0",
    "angular-gridster": "0.13.15",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.8",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.12.1",
    "jszip": "^2.4.0",
    "kendo-ui": "https://schmidt%40cargoclix.com:cargoclix@bower.telerik.com/bower-kendo-ui.git#^2016.3.1007",
    "json-human": "0.1.1",
    "angular-base64-upload": "0.1.19",
    "ngclipboard": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-hotkeys": "chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys#^1.7.0",
    "underscore": "1.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.4.4",
    "angular-translate": "~2.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-ajax": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.6"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": ">=1.9.1 <=2.1.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Waiting for great solution.Thanks

Comment: The provided information does not suggest the cause of the problem. Please edit your question and include the Grid declaration with some dummy data, so that the error can be reproduced on a simple test page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What jQuery version are you using? I had similar problems and worked when I updated jQuery to version 2.2.4 or above.

Comment: I updated jQuery to 3.1.1, This fixed my issue. Thanks