# Kendo grid's export to excel throws jquery error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I have asp.net core application using Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core. I am trying to use [export to excel feature](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/excel-export) as per the demo. However i am getting jQuery error

> cannot read property 'length' of undefine

as per [SO suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139074/error-in-kendo-grid-export-to-excel-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) i have to upgrade jquery to 2.2.4 or above.
However when i checked the bower configuration for kendo-ui it has jQuery dependency.

```
{
  "name": "kendo-ui",
  "version": "2016.3.1007",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.9.1 <=2.1.1"
  },

   //removed for brevity
}
```

so the kendo-ui has dependency on jquery version <= 2.1.1 so i could not upgrade jQuery. (also my license for kendo is expired so i could not upgrade Kendo as well)

So what are my options here to get around this issue?

Comment: Kendo Grid is not available in the free version anymore.

Comment: @CarlosMartins we are using licensed version